# how to create executable static library in android?

Tags: android, static

I ask somthing about static library..

" how to create executable static library in android?"

and

"How to connect static library in eclipse?"

Static library is a binary file, How to understand static library in jni?

I wondering static library operation method in android.. (such as static library in vc++)

I'm exptected your reply.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this tutorial: [Writing C code for Android](http://www.linux-mag.com/cache/7697/1.html)

Essentially, you will need a compiler that would compile your C/C++ code for the Android platform. Android comes with Native development toolkit(NDK) that you can download: it will aid you in writing and compiling executables(.so) files for the Android platform. You can then use JNI to interface Java with native code.

You can download the NDK from the official site: [see here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/1.6_r1/index.html). By default the NDK contains a Hello_World_JNI program that you can look at for starters.